# I can't find row in gridview's RowDataBound, gives exception"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am working with `gridview`, i want change color of specific row into grid view thats why i must find row at rowdatabound event. How i find the row?

Source code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arr={"1","2","3","4"};
    GridView1.DataSource = arr;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void pagechangin(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) {
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
}
protected void databound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    GridViewRow grv=GridView1.Rows[0];
}
```

Comment: Your code shows you trying to access a specific row in the databound event (which isn't proper). What are you attempting to achieve? Knowing this might help determine what your next steps should be.

Comment: Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You must register an event-handler to handle an event. But you haven't shown us the aspx markup, so maybe you have missed to add the handler declaratively:

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" 
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
    runat="server">
  </asp:gridview>

void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         // e.Row is the GridViewRow
         e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
}
```

**Update** The reason for the `IndexOutOfRangeException` is that you are accessing the first row before it is created:

```
GridViewRow grv=GridView1.Rows[0];
```

This is a nasty one. `RowDataBound` is called for every `GridViewRow`, not only for the `DataItems` but also for the `Header`,`Footer` and `Pager`. The first one that will be created is the `Header`. But `GridView.Rows` does return only `GridViewRows` with `RowType` = `DataRow`. So you are trying to access the first "data-row" during the creation of the `header` row.

To fix it use the code above and check the `RowType`.

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    // now you ca safely access the first row in this way, 
    // altghough i assume that you should use my code above 
    // to set the color of every GridViewRow
    GridViewRow grv=GridView1.Rows[0];
```

Apart from that you should also `DataBind` the grid only `if(!IsPostBack)` as Dragan has mentioned if you're using `ViewState` (default).

Comment: problem remain same ..i still get same error if i attempt to find grid view row using GridViewRow grv=GridView1.Rows[0];

Comment: @user1936466: `GridViewRow grv=GridView1.Rows[0];` is what you have mistakenly used to find the first row, i've recommended to use `RowDataBound` witht he correct `RowType`. Note that `RowDataBound` is triggered for every row in the `GridView`, not just for one. So the code i've shown at last is not best-practise or recommended at all since you would look at the first row for every row which is unlikely to be useful. **Instead use `e.Row`** as i've shown first.

Comment: i have find another best way color row at onprerender event of gridview.

Comment: @user1936466: Best place is `RowDataBound` since it is called for every row anyway and only when the grid was databound. Since the color is stored in ViewState it is pointless to set it on every postback.

Answer (score 1):

Your page_load event handler is not correct. Yoou shouldn't load the data on every page load but only on the initial. Maybe this is causing problems.

Try this in your Page_Load method

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
{
    //copy your code from above
}
```

Comment: Problem is not that..You cant understand nature of problem properly.